# Find number of elements in range from map object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Map structure and data is given below

```
Map<String, BigDecimal>
```

- A, 12
- B, 23
- C, 67
- D, 99

Now i want to group values in range, output has range as key and number of elements there as value. Like below:

- 0-25, 2
- 26-50, 0
- 51-75, 1
- 76-100, 1

How can we do this using java streams ?

Comment: can you use `guava`?

Comment: I can use that if something like this readily available there, excited to learn something new!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, BigDecimal> aMap=new HashMap<>();

        aMap.put("A",new BigDecimal(12));
        aMap.put("B",new BigDecimal(23));
        aMap.put("C",new BigDecimal(67));
        aMap.put("D",new BigDecimal(99));
         Map<String, Long> o =  aMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy( a ->{
             //Do the logic here to return the group by function
             if(a.getValue().compareTo(new BigDecimal(0))>0 &&
                     a.getValue().compareTo(new BigDecimal(25))<0)
                 return "0-25";

             if(a.getValue().compareTo(new BigDecimal(26))>0 &&
                     a.getValue().compareTo(new BigDecimal(50))<0)
                 return "26-50";

             if(a.getValue().compareTo(new BigDecimal(51))>0 &&
                     a.getValue().compareTo(new BigDecimal(75))<0)
                 return "51-75";
             if(a.getValue().compareTo(new BigDecimal(76))>0 &&
                     a.getValue().compareTo(new BigDecimal(100))<0)
                 return "76-100";

             return "not-found";
         }, Collectors.counting()));

         System.out.print("Result="+o);


    }

}
```

Result is : Result={0-25=2, 76-100=1, 51-75=1}

I couldn't find a better way to do that check for big decimals but you can think about how to improve it :) Maybe make an external method that does that trick

Answer (score 5):

You may use a solution for regular ranges, e.g.

```
BigDecimal range = BigDecimal.valueOf(25);
inputMap.values().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            bd -> bd.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE).divide(range, 0, RoundingMode.DOWN),
            TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
        .forEach((group,count) -> {
            group = group.multiply(range);
            System.out.printf("%3.0f - %3.0f: %s%n",
                              group.add(BigDecimal.ONE), group.add(range), count);
        });
```

which will print:

```
  1 -  25: 2
 51 -  75: 1
 76 - 100: 1
```

<sup>(not using the irregular range `0 - 25`)</sup>

or a solution with explicit ranges:

```
TreeMap<BigDecimal,String> ranges = new TreeMap<>();
ranges.put(BigDecimal.ZERO,        " 0 - 25");
ranges.put(BigDecimal.valueOf(26), "26 - 50");
ranges.put(BigDecimal.valueOf(51), "51 - 75");
ranges.put(BigDecimal.valueOf(76), "76 - 99");
ranges.put(BigDecimal.valueOf(100),">= 100 ");

inputMap.values().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            bd -> ranges.floorEntry(bd).getValue(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
        .forEach((group,count) -> System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", group, count));
```

```
 0 - 25: 2
51 - 75: 1
76 - 99: 1
```

which can also get extended to print the absent ranges:

```
Map<BigDecimal, Long> groupToCount = inputMap.values().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(bd -> ranges.floorKey(bd), Collectors.counting()));
ranges.forEach((k, g) -> System.out.println(g+": "+groupToCount.getOrDefault(k, 0L)));
```

```
 0 - 25: 2
26 - 50: 0
51 - 75: 1
76 - 99: 1
>= 100 : 0
```

But note that putting numeric values into ranges like, e.g. “0 - 25” and “26 - 50” only makes sense if we’re talking about whole numbers, precluding values between 25 and 26, raising the question why you’re using `BigDecimal` instead of `BigInteger`. For decimal numbers, you would normally use ranges like “0 (inclusive) - 25 (exclusive)” and “25 (inclusive) - 50 (exclusive)”, etc.

Comment: I completely agree with you, actually here it is hypothetical scenario based on my use case.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `Range` like this:

```
class Range {
    private final BigDecimal start;
    private final BigDecimal end;

    public Range(BigDecimal start, BigDecimal end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public boolean inRange(BigDecimal val) {
        return val.compareTo(start) >= 0 && val.compareTo(end) <= 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return start + "-" + end;
    }

}
```

You can do this:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> input = new HashMap<>();
input.put("A", BigDecimal.valueOf(12));
input.put("B", BigDecimal.valueOf(23));
input.put("C", BigDecimal.valueOf(67));
input.put("D", BigDecimal.valueOf(99));

List<Range> ranges = new ArrayList<>();
ranges.add(new Range(BigDecimal.valueOf(0), BigDecimal.valueOf(25)));       
ranges.add(new Range(BigDecimal.valueOf(26), BigDecimal.valueOf(50)));
ranges.add(new Range(BigDecimal.valueOf(51), BigDecimal.valueOf(75)));
ranges.add(new Range(BigDecimal.valueOf(76), BigDecimal.valueOf(100)));

Map<Range, Long> result = new HashMap<>();
ranges.forEach(r -> result.put(r, 0L)); // Add all ranges with a count of 0
input.values().forEach( // For each value in the map
        bd -> ranges.stream() 
            .filter(r -> r.inRange(bd)) // Find ranges it is in (can be in multiple)
            .forEach(r -> result.put(r, result.get(r) + 1)) // And increment their count
    );

System.out.println(result); // {51-75=1, 76-100=1, 26-50=0, 0-25=2}
```

I also had a solution with the `groupingBy` collector, but it was twice as big and couldn't deal with overlapping ranges or values that weren't in any range, so I think a solution like this will be better.

Comment: if only `RangeMap` from guava, had methods like `replace/computeIfAbsent/computeIfPresent`..

Comment: @Eugene Well, you could always add it yourself I guess (yay open source) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html):

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> dataSet = new HashMap<>();
dataSet.put("A", new BigDecimal(12));
dataSet.put("B", new BigDecimal(23));
dataSet.put("C", new BigDecimal(67));
dataSet.put("D", new BigDecimal(99));

// Map(k=MinValue, v=Count)
NavigableMap<BigDecimal, Integer> partitions = new TreeMap<>();
partitions.put(new BigDecimal(0), 0);
partitions.put(new BigDecimal(25), 0);
partitions.put(new BigDecimal(50), 0);
partitions.put(new BigDecimal(75), 0);
partitions.put(new BigDecimal(100), 0);

for (BigDecimal d : dataSet.values()) {
  Entry<BigDecimal, Integer> e = partitions.floorEntry(d);
  partitions.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue() + 1);
}

partitions.forEach((k, count) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + count));
// 0: 2
// 25: 0
// 50: 1
// 75: 1
// 100: 0
```

Comment: You can also use `partitions.merge(partitions.floorKey(d), 1, Integer::sum);`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that @Holger

Answer (score 1):

If only `RangeMap` from guava had methods like `replace` of `computeIfPresent/computeIfAbsent` like the additions in java-8 `Map` do, this would have been a breeze to do. Otherwise it's a bit cumbersome:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> left = new HashMap<>();

left.put("A", new BigDecimal(12));
left.put("B", new BigDecimal(23));
left.put("C", new BigDecimal(67));
left.put("D", new BigDecimal(99));



    RangeMap<BigDecimal, Long> ranges = TreeRangeMap.create();
    ranges.put(Range.closedOpen(new BigDecimal(0), new BigDecimal(25)), 0L);
    ranges.put(Range.closedOpen(new BigDecimal(25), new BigDecimal(50)), 0L);
    ranges.put(Range.closedOpen(new BigDecimal(50), new BigDecimal(75)), 0L);
    ranges.put(Range.closedOpen(new BigDecimal(75), new BigDecimal(100)), 0L);

    left.values()
            .stream()
            .forEachOrdered(x -> {
                Entry<Range<BigDecimal>, Long> e = ranges.getEntry(x);
                ranges.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue() + 1);
            });

    System.out.println(ranges);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which you can use:

```
    public static void groupByRange() {
        List<MyBigDecimal> bigDecimals = new ArrayList<MyBigDecimal>();
        for(int i =0; i<= 10; i++) {
            MyBigDecimal md = new MyBigDecimal();
            if(i>0 && i<= 2)
                md.setRange(1);
            else if(i>2 && i<= 5)
                md.setRange(2);
            else if(i>5 && i<= 7)
                md.setRange(3);
            else
                md.setRange(4);
            md.setValue(i);

            bigDecimals.add(md);
        }


        Map<Integer, List<MyBigDecimal>>  result = bigDecimals.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getRange(), 
                        Collector.of(
                                ArrayList :: new, 
                                (list, elem) -> { 
                                                        if (list.size() < 2) 
                                                            list.add(elem); 
                                                    }, 
                                (list1, list2) -> {
                                         list1.addAll(list2);
                                    return list1;
                                }
                           )));

        for(Entry<Integer, List<MyBigDecimal>> en : result.entrySet()) {
            int in = en.getKey();
            List<MyBigDecimal> cours  = en.getValue();
            System.out.println("Key Range = "+in + " , List Size : "+cours.size());
        }


    }


class MyBigDecimal{


    private int range;
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getRange() {
        return range;
    }

    public void setRange(int range) {
        this.range = range;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a similar result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> resMap = new HashMap<>();
    int range = 25;

    Map<String, BigDecimal> aMap=new HashMap<>();

    aMap.put("A",new BigDecimal(12));
    aMap.put("B",new BigDecimal(23));
    aMap.put("C",new BigDecimal(67));
    aMap.put("D",new BigDecimal(99));

    aMap.values().forEach(v -> {
        int lower = v.divide(new BigDecimal(range)).intValue();
        // get the lower & add the range to get higher
        String key = lower*range + "-" + (lower*range+range-1);
        resMap.put(key, resMap.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
    });

    resMap.entrySet().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " = " + e.getValue()));
}
```

Though there are some differences from what you have asked

- Ranges are inclusive in this; 0-24 instead of 0-25, so that 25 is included in 25-50
- Your range 0-25 contains 26 possible values in between, while all other ranges contain 25 values. This implementations output has ranges of size 25 (configurable via range variable)
- You can decide on the range

Output (you may want to iterate the map's key better to get the output in a sorted order)

```
75-99 = 1
0-24 = 2
50-74 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your range has the value `BigDecimal.valueOf(26)`, you can do the following to get a `Map<BigDecimal, Long>` where each key represents the group id (0 for [0-25], 1 for [26, 51], ...), and each corresponding value represents the group count of elements.

```
content.values()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> n.divide(range, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR), Collectors.counting()))
```